# Where can I find usage Heatmaps of common user interfaces?

Tags: usability-study, heatmaps

I found this amazing [Mozilla Firefox usage Heatmap](https://heatmap.mozillalabs.com/) and find it a great insight into the usage of Firefox and browsers in general.

Are there other resources which have similar heatmaps for use of popular applications publicly or otherwise available?

Comment: Microsoft published a few heatmaps justifying their design decisions for Windows 8 on [their Building Windows 8 blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/10/11/reflecting-on-your-comments-on-the-start-screen.aspx).

Comment: Just to note that heatmaps might be misleading if interpreted out of context: caution should be taken when heat maps are presented without additional information such as the user intended goal, what they said, what they did, etc. Harry Brignull provides [a critical view on heatmap interpreatation](http://www.slideshare.net/harrybr/what-you-need-to-know-about-eye-tracking-new-uxlx-version) explaining these points.

Comment: Does the 95% on the scroll bar include scroll wheel and track pad scrolling? I rarely see people scroll this way...

Comment: @BillCriswell nope! Read the description of the scroll bar and it's clicks only. I was surprised too, check the clicks per user too.

Answer (score 3):

The Etre blog published [Five days / five heatmaps post](http://www.etre.com/blog/2006/05/five_days_five_heatmaps/), where the following websites were analyzed:

- Dixons.co.uk
- Currys.co.uk
- Amazon.co.uk
- MarksAndSpencer.com
- HMV.co.uk
- M&S revisited

As it is stated in the study, the goal for users was very general ("to explore each website"):

> Users were asked simply to explore each website. (While we were only
>   interested in their interactions with the homepage, we didn't want to
>   artificially influence their natural browsing behaviour by
>   constraining them to only that page).

Answer (score 2):

The one and only Jakob Nielsen has written a whole book on the subject called [Eyetracking Web Usability](http://books.google.es/books/about/Eyetracking_Web_Usability.html?id=EeQhHqjgQosC&redir_esc=y), some articles are available in [his site](http://www.useit.com/eyetracking/).